# Error al cargar imágenes con Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

¡Hola buenas!

Tengo el siguiente error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

El código es el siguiente:

*js*

```
Vue.component('movie-card',{
    props : ['image','title'],
    template: `
        <div>
            <h2> {{title}} </h2>
            <img v-bind:src="image" v-bind:alt="title" />  
        </div>
    `
})


new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    data : {
        movies : [
            {title: 'Star Wars: Los Últimos Jedi', imagen: 'https://pics.filmaffinity.com/star_wars_the_last_jedi-535293064-mmed.jpg'},
            {title: 'Vengadores: La era de Ultrón', imagen: 'https://pics.filmaffinity.com/avengers_age_of_ultron_the_avengers_2-182285335-mmed.jpg'},
            {title: 'El Hobbit: La desolación de Smaug', imagen: 'https://pics.filmaffinity.com/the_hobbit_the_desolation_of_smaug-498845622-mmed.jpg'}
        ]
    },
    template : `
    <div>
    <movie-card 
        v-for="(movie,index) in movies"
        :key="index"
        :title="movie.title"
        :image="movie.imagen"
    ></movie-card>
    </div>
    `
})
```

*html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Movie Cards</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

El fallo esta al cargar las imágenes, ya que el error me sale por cada enlace. Los enlaces no están caidos ni nada, asi que no se que podrá ser. Espero respuesta, un saludo.

Comment: Hola. Metí tu codigo en un snippet de codigo en la prgunta (en el modo edicion, pulsa en `<>`) y funciona sin errores...

Comment: He probado mi codigo en mi maquina y si funciona, quizas eliminando el cache de tu navegador funcione, me ha pasado con chrome almacene los js's en cache